# What's the easiest way to get Google Places data?

Tags: google-search, google-my-business

Here is an example of the data that I want.

[image: Picture of the data I want]

Answer (score 2):

You could use Google Maps. Example: https://www.google.com/maps/search/breweries+near+boston/@42.3499212,-71.1776789,12z/data=!3m1!4b1

[image: Google Maps: breweries near Boston]

Comment: Besides Maps and regular Web search, I don't see a way to get those "cards".